# I need binary and hex syntax translations for type num

Tags: isabelle

I ask my question first.

**Question:** I need binary and hex syntax for the `num` datatype. Is there some source somewhere I can easily adapt? Can someone provide it for me? Or, does it already exist?

The numeral type class allows the use of binary and hexadecimal notation, such as `0b0101` and `0xAA`. However, `num` is not instantiated as `numeral`, and I only see the constructors used directly, such as with this source:

```
primrec sqr :: "num => num" where
  "sqr One = One" |
  "sqr (Bit0 n) = Bit0 (Bit0 (sqr n))" |
  "sqr (Bit1 n) = Bit1 (Bit0 (sqr n + n))"
```

Below, I include a complete theory in which I've defined notation to allow me to use binary and hex notation with `num`, but it's not standard notation. The notation I have is acceptable, but it looks like it could eventually cause some conflicts.

I was initially building tables to learn how `One`, `Bit0`, and `Bit1` are used to create a binary number. It was tricky at first, because the order of bits is reversed from normal, along with a few other quirks, but I finally got it. For anyone interested, there are some things that are good to know about `num`, along with a [numeral wiki page](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/community/Numerals):

- The most significant digit is on the right, not on the left.
- The `num` type has no zero, so the rightmost digit will always be 1, though the rightmost digit increases in value by powers of 2 when you add enough digits on the left.
- Adding zeros on the left makes a number bigger.

The included theory is too involved to convert it to ASCII. Some might be interested in loading it in the PIDE to look at it. I show a use for the notation at the bottom, where I define the function `num_left_shift`.

I'm just looking for syntax that has a 2 character prefix, like `0u1010101`, along with hex syntax like `0m555`. The translation of the syntax would build up a number from the `num` constructors.

I couldn't get `translations` to work for me. I also see the use of `parse_translation` in Num.thy, but I don't know how to use it.

### Update: 140326

I update this to answer Brian Huffman's question. I do it here since it will take more characters than a comment allows. Brian's question is this:

> Is there a reason why you need to use type num directly? Why not define a separate type of naturals > 0, and make it an instance of class numeral?

The short answer is that I don't need `num` because it has no zero, I need it because that's the only way I know of to use `fun` with binary and hex at the bit level. In particular, I'm talking about pattern matching with `fun`, on binary and hex patterns.

From here, I talk about how `num` is part of my grand scheme, and why I think I need it to do a binary bit shift.

### Numeral for abstraction, nat for Suc, and num for One, Bit0, and Bit1

This is related to my plans to eventually try and do a lot of work in algebra type classes.

Take the type class `linordered_idom`. How do I fully exploit the power of HOL for that type class? I don't, because I don't have a constructor to work with.

I spent a number of days trying to use `datatype` and `typedef` to put a constructor on `UNIV::'a::linordered_idom set`, though it also involved zero having its own constructor.

It sort of worked, but it was a bunch of clutter, and not a completely good solution.

That led to my idea to use `nat` as a means to front all numbers, using `numeral(num_of_nat)`.

As part of that I defined a function to calculate the number of digits in a decimal number:

```
fun dec_digits :: "nat => nat" where
  "dec_digits n = (if (n div 10 = 0) then 1 else 1 + dec_digits(n div 10))"
```

I assume that a bit shift operation on a binary number is faster than `div`, so I started pursuing a binary bit shift function to use with binary and hex numbers, and that led to `num`.

This ties back into the section title above. With `nat`, I get a constructor for building numbers by adding one. But how do I do binary bit shifts using `nat`?

There's a lot I don't know about `numeral` and `num`, but my conclusion is that as a complete solution for working with numbers, I need to work with all three of `numeral`, `num`, and `nat`.

### The left bit shift for binary and hex division

The function `num_left_shift` is part of the culmination of my preliminary effort to get some basic ideas settled for the future, in relation to number systems, and their relation to algebraic type classes.

The type `nat` is foundational to HOL, and `fun` works a lot of magic with it. The `numeral` type class gives me an abstract set of number constants, where you work a lot of low-level magic for it with the algebraic binary operations.

But how do I manipulate numbers based on their structure? I know there's a lot of math in HOL, like `div` and `mod`, but how do I do binary bit shifts without using `num`?

All I know right now is how to use `num` to do that for binary and hex. If there's a high level way to do that, I'll be happy to learn about it.

One question I still have is this, "How do I manipulate numbers in HOL based on decimal digits, without using `div`?

```
(******************************************************************************)
theory i140326a_num_bin_hex_notation
imports Complex_Main 
begin
(******************************************************************************)
(*NOTE
(1) The binary and hex notation for num can't prevent fun from directly
    using the num constructors. One main use for fun is to do pattern matching
    on binary and hex number patterns.
*)
notation 
  numeral ("N\<^sub>a:_" [1000] 1000)
abbreviation nat_numeral :: "num \<Rightarrow> nat" where
  "nat_numeral n == (numeral n)::nat"   
notation 
  nat_numeral ("N\<^sub>n:_" [1000] 1000)
notation
  nat_of_num ("\<nn>:_" [1000] 1000)
notation
  num_of_nat ("\<uu>:_" [1000] 1000)
notation Num.One  ("1\<^sub>1:")
notation Num.Bit0 ("0:_" [1000] 1000)
notation Num.Bit1 ("1:_" [1000] 1000)

value "\<uu>:0b0000" (*.................One..*) (*.......0:0:0:0..................*)
value "\<uu>:0b0001" (*                 One  *) value "\<nn>:      1\<^sub>1:" term "      1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b0010" (*            Bit0 One  *) value "\<nn>:    0:1\<^sub>1:" term "    0:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b0011" (*            Bit1 One  *) value "\<nn>:    1:1\<^sub>1:" term "    1:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b0100" (*      Bit0 (Bit0 One) *) value "\<nn>:  0:0:1\<^sub>1:" term "  0:0:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b0101" (*      Bit1 (Bit0 One) *) value "\<nn>:  1:0:1\<^sub>1:" term "  1:0:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b0110" (*      Bit0 (Bit1 One) *) value "\<nn>:  0:1:1\<^sub>1:" term "  0:1:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b0111" (*      Bit1 (Bit1 One) *) value "\<nn>:  1:1:1\<^sub>1:" term "  1:1:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b1000" (*Bit0 (Bit0 (Bit0 One))*) value "\<nn>:0:0:0:1\<^sub>1:" term "0:0:0:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b1001" (*Bit1 (Bit0 (Bit0 One))*) value "\<nn>:1:0:0:1\<^sub>1:" term "1:0:0:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b1010" (*Bit0 (Bit1 (Bit0 One))*) value "\<nn>:0:1:0:1\<^sub>1:" term "0:1:0:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b1011" (*Bit1 (Bit1 (Bit0 One))*) value "\<nn>:1:1:0:1\<^sub>1:" term "1:1:0:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b1100" (*Bit0 (Bit0 (Bit1 One))*) value "\<nn>:0:0:1:1\<^sub>1:" term "0:0:1:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b1101" (*Bit1 (Bit0 (Bit1 One))*) value "\<nn>:1:0:1:1\<^sub>1:" term "1:0:1:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b1110" (*Bit0 (Bit1 (Bit1 One))*) value "\<nn>:0:1:1:1\<^sub>1:" term "0:1:1:1\<^sub>1:"
value "\<uu>:0b1111" (*Bit1 (Bit1 (Bit1 One))*) value "\<nn>:1:1:1:1\<^sub>1:" term "1:1:1:1\<^sub>1:"

lemma "\<nn>:0:0:0:1\<^sub>1: = 0b1000" by simp

(*|HEX FIRST RIGHT DIGITS.|*)
(*|Digits 1-7 are used with nothing to the left, and 0 is never a first digit|*)
abbreviation (input) "h0x1 ==       1\<^sub>1:" notation h0x1 ("1\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0x2 ==     0:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0x2 ("2\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0x3 ==     1:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0x3 ("3\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0x4 ==   0:0:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0x4 ("4\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0x5 ==   1:0:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0x5 ("5\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0x6 ==   0:1:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0x6 ("6\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0x7 ==   1:1:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0x7 ("7\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
(*|Digits 8-F can be used alone, or with digits to the left.|*)
abbreviation (input) "h0x8 == 0:0:0:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0x8 ("8\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0x9 == 1:0:0:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0x9 ("9\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0xA == 0:1:0:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0xA ("A\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0xB == 1:1:0:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0xB ("B\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0xC == 0:0:1:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0xC ("C\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0xD == 1:0:1:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0xD ("D\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0xE == 0:1:1:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0xE ("E\<^sub>1\<cdot>")
abbreviation (input) "h0xF == 1:1:1:1\<^sub>1:" notation h0xF ("F\<^sub>1\<cdot>") 

(*|HEX MIDDLE DIGITS AND LEFT DIGITS|*)
abbreviation (input) lh0x0 :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("0\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0x0 n == 0:0:0:0:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0x1 :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("1\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000)
  where "lh0x1 n == 1:0:0:0:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0x2 :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("2\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0x2 n == 0:1:0:0:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0x3 :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("3\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0x3 n == 1:1:0:0:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0x4 :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("4\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0x4 n == 0:0:1:0:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0x5 :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("5\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0x5 n == 1:0:1:0:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0x6 :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("6\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0x6 n == 0:1:1:0:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0x7 :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("7\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0x7 n == 1:1:1:0:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0x8 :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("8\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0x8 n == 0:0:0:1:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0x9 :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("9\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0x9 n == 1:0:0:1:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0xA :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("A\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0xA n == 0:1:0:1:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0xB :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("B\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0xB n == 1:1:0:1:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0xC :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("C\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0xC n == 0:0:1:1:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0xD :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("D\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0xD n == 1:0:1:1:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0xE :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("E\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0xE n == 0:1:1:1:n"
abbreviation (input) lh0xF :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" ("F\<cdot>_" [1000] 1000) 
  where "lh0xF n == 1:1:1:1:n"
  
lemma "N\<^sub>a:0\<cdot>1\<cdot>2\<cdot>3\<cdot>4\<cdot>5\<cdot>6\<cdot>7\<cdot>8\<cdot>9\<cdot>A\<cdot>B\<cdot>C\<cdot>D\<cdot>E\<cdot>F\<^sub>1\<cdot> = 0xFEDCBA9876543210"
  by(rule refl)
  
lemma "N\<^sub>n:0\<cdot>1\<cdot>2\<cdot>3\<cdot>4\<cdot>5\<cdot>6\<cdot>7\<cdot>8\<cdot>9\<cdot>A\<cdot>B\<cdot>C\<cdot>D\<cdot>E\<cdot>F\<^sub>1\<cdot> = 0xFEDCBA9876543210"
  by(rule refl)

value "\<nn>:1\<cdot>8\<^sub>1\<cdot>" term "1\<cdot>8\<^sub>1\<cdot>" value "numeral 1\<cdot>8\<^sub>1\<cdot>"
value "\<nn>:2\<cdot>8\<^sub>1\<cdot>" term "2\<cdot>8\<^sub>1\<cdot>" value "numeral 2\<cdot>8\<^sub>1\<cdot>"
value "\<nn>:3\<cdot>8\<^sub>1\<cdot>" term "3\<cdot>8\<^sub>1\<cdot>" value "numeral 3\<cdot>8\<^sub>1\<cdot>"

(******************************************************************************)
(* SHIFT OPERATIONS *)
(******************************************************************************)

fun num_left_shift :: "num \<Rightarrow> num" where
  "num_left_shift 1\<^sub>1: = 1\<^sub>1:"
 |"num_left_shift (0:1\<^sub>1:) = 1\<^sub>1:"
 |"num_left_shift (1:1\<^sub>1:) = 1\<^sub>1:"
 |"num_left_shift (0:0:n) = 0:(num_left_shift 0:n)"
 |"num_left_shift (0:1:n) = 1:(num_left_shift 1:n)"
 |"num_left_shift (1:0:n) = 0:(num_left_shift 0:n)"
 |"num_left_shift (1:1:n) = 1:(num_left_shift 1:n)"
 
value "num_left_shift A\<cdot>A\<^sub>1\<cdot>"
value "num_left_shift 5\<cdot>D\<^sub>1\<cdot>"

(******************************************************************************)
end
(******************************************************************************)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use type `num` directly? Why not define a separate type of naturals > 0, and make it an instance of class `numeral`?

Comment: @Brian, thanks for your time. I tried to answer your question with an update above. Numeral and num is a big part of HOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I finish this to my satisfaction. It's not that I still wouldn't like some kind of answer from a developer, but I don't want to waste their time when things are changing.

I show here that I've changed from wanting to use `num` directly, to wanting to use `(num => num) list`, which has changed the need for how the syntax is implemented.

There are two limitations to `num`, that it has no zero, and that with pattern matching, I can only have one variable on the right-hand side, and all my bit patterns have to be constructors.

The consequence is that if I want to match on `n` bits, I have to have `(n+1) - 1` cases, where if I'm wrong on some details here, it's not important right now.

Here, I show it takes 15 cases to match on 3 bits:

```
notation Num.One  (":1:")
notation Num.Bit0 ("0:_" [1000] 1000)
notation Num.Bit1 ("1:_" [1000] 1000)

fun xp_3_bit_match :: "num => num" where
  "xp_3_bit_match :1: = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (0::1:) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (1::1:) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (0:0::1:) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (1:0::1:) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (0:1::1:) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (1:1::1:) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (0:0:0:n) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (1:0:0:n) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (0:1:0:n) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (1:1:0:n) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (0:0:1:n) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (1:0:1:n) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (0:1:1:n) = :1:"
 |"xp_3_bit_match (1:1:1:n) = :1:"
```

Next, I do pattern matching on type `(num => num) list`, and it reduces the 15 cases to 4. The first case for `[]` gives me a zero if I'm mapping `num` to `nat`, or vice versa.

```
notation (input) Num.Bit0 ("\<zero>")
notation (input) Num.Bit1 ("\<one>")

fun num_num_3_match :: "(num => num) list => num" where
  "num_num_3_match []                  = Num.One"
 |"num_num_3_match [_]                 = Num.One"
 |"num_num_3_match [b1,_]              = b1(Num.One)"
 |"num_num_3_match [b1,b2,_]           = b2(b1(Num.One))"
 |"num_num_3_match (b1 # b2 # b3 # bs) = b3(b2(b1(num_num_3_match bs)))"

 term "num_num_3_match [\<one>,\<one>,\<zero>,\<zero>,\<one>,\<one>]"
 value "num_num_3_match [\<one>,\<one>,\<zero>,\<zero>,\<one>,\<one>]"
```

But, with constructors, rather than variables, I'm getting exception errors, but that's probably because I'm using contructors.

```
fun numL :: "(num => num) list => nat" where        
  "numL []  = 0"
 |"numL [_] = 1"
 |"numL [Num.Bit0,_] = 1" 

 (*exception Option raised (line 81 of "General/basics.ML")*)        

fun numL :: "(nat => nat) list => nat" where
  "numL []  = 0"
 |"numL [Suc,_] = 1"
```